# Capture text after lookahead

Tags: regex

I have a text, which is some text, folllowed by either `<null>` or a path, and something in a paranthese at the end. I want to capture pattern1 and pattern2 (with .. or / at the beginning):

```
pattern1 <null> (not important)
pattern1 ../pattern2 (not important)
pattern1 /pattern2 (not important)
```

I expected that concatenating the 2nd and 3rd capture groups I get pattern2, but not

```
(.+)(?=(<null>|( \.\.| \/)))(.+)(.*)(?= \()
```

Input: `pthread_create /usr/include/c++/5/thread:115 (library)`
Result:

```
pthread_create
 /
 /
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Try [`(.+?)(<null>| (?:\.\.\/|\/))(.*?)(?= \()`](https://regex101.com/r/uY0tD7/2).

Comment: @Wiktor: thank you, it works. If you have a little time can you explain what was wrong with my expression? And what is the ?: structure it your solution? It does not seem to me like a looahead.

Comment: It is not a lookahead, it is a non-capturing group.

Comment: I think the point is the `/`, right? It is just not matched with the two dot alternative branch inside the capturing group in the lookahead (I think this lookahead is redundant, thus, I just moved the contents to the consuming pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, `\.\.` matches the two dots, but does not capture the `/` after them, thus, it [lands in Group 4](https://regex101.com/r/sO2zJ1/1). Also, there is no point in keeping a positive lookahead with a capture group inside it, since it creates unnecessary groups in the results, you can move the `(<null>|( \.\.| \/))` to the consuming pattern part.

You can use

```
(.+?)(<null>| (?:\.\.\/|\/))(.*?)(?= \()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY0tD7/2)

The pattern matches:

- `(.+?)` - (Group 1) one or more any characters other than a newline, as few as possible up to the first occurrence of...
- `(<null>| (?:\.\.\/|\/))` - (Group 2) `<null>` or a space followed with `../` or `/`
- `(.*?)(?= \()` - (Group 3) zero or more any characters but a newline as few as possible up to the first occurrence of a space followed with `(`.